# Why other components does not render inside of Layout in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, layout

I have a structure as below in React:

```
  client.js // routes are defined here and rendered app

  components // a directory with all header, footer, layout, etc components
  |
  \____ Header.js   
  \____ Layout.js
  \____ Nav.js
  \____ Setting.js

  index.html
```

Now inside of `Layout.js` I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Nav from './Nav';
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
        super();
  }
render() {
    return (
     <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Nav />
        <div className="container" style={{marginTop: '60px'}}>
                {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My `client.js` is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Archive from './components/Archive.js';
import Layout from './components/Layout.js';
import Featured  from './components/Featured.js';
import Setting  from './components/Setting.js';
import { HashRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
        (<HashRouter>
                <div>
                        <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
                        <Route path="/archive/:aid?" component={Archive} />
                        <Route path="/featured" component={Featured} />
                        <Route path="/setting" component={Setting} />
                </div>
        </HashRouter>),
document.getElementById('app'));
```

The problem is that when I navigate through links, it renders content of let's say `archive` after `Footer`:

[image]

**NB: `I'm in archive page` is rendered after footer section**

What is wrong here? And what should I do to render components inside of layout?

Comment: Remove style={{marginTop: '60px'}} in container then the page content will go up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
<Layout>
    <Route path="/archive/:aid?" component={Archive} />
    <Route path="/featured" component={Featured} />
    <Route path="/setting" component={Setting} />
</Layout>
```

Comment: `margin-top` shifts the whole page except `navbar` to 60px below the nav. My problem is that `Footer` is before `Component content like archive`. I want components to be rendered inside of layout.

Comment: OK got it. You can put all pages inside Layout as     <Route path="/" component={Layout}>//Your page roots here</Route>.

Comment: I've got the error of `You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`